# Pass current scope with ng-click inside template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there a way to pass current scope to the function using ng-click ? Something like this:

```
ng-click='loadDatA($scope)'
```

I have very specific situation where the template is compiled with a custom isolated scope, and then controller on that scope is adding new data to the scope. My goal is to pass that changed scope to the function that will compile another template(`loadData` in this example) but will pass this modified scope to it.

Now, this could be done easily if the `loadData` is actually defined inside the controller and have directly access to the scope, but this is not the case. `loaData` is actually defined on the custom scope that is passed to the template.

Comment: you could use `$scope` inheritance for parent scope you could use `$parent` , but I'm curious to know why you want to pass whole scope?

Comment: well, the idea is that directive renders a new template with a custom scope which will have loadData function attached to it. At first, that scope will be empty and the controller in charge of that template will have opportunity to change it. However, I want to load a different template when a specific element is clicked(ng-click=loadData), but I would like to pass to that template also the data that the previous controller could set. Generally, I want to have steps, in step1 controller sets some data and then another step should have access to that data. This works except the scope part.

Comment: looks like this can be done by isolated scope, and pass whichever scope variable you want to pass to directive..

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean but $parent actually works in my case. loadData is defined inside directive that compiles template against some scope, so now I could pass this scope to the $compile and the new template will have access to the data.

Comment: yeah..you could always access child scope in the isolated directive using `$parent.scope`